# Xamarin Instantiate Initial Navigation Controller in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sigint

I have a navigation controller as my initial view controller. It's root view controller is "StartingViewController". That view controller was generated by the storyboard.

The automatically generated constructor is:

```
public StartingViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
```

However, when I use this constructor, I get the error "`object reference not set to an object`" when I try to access any of my outlets. Eg.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            label.Text = "hi";
        }
```

However something like this works fine:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }
```

I tried to use a different constructor:

```
public StartingViewController() : base ("StartingViewController", null)
{
}
```

For this, I don't get a the previous error, but no code runs in the `ViewDidLoad()` and it prints a warning, `"Ignoring invocation of an instance method on a NULL instance"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatically generated constructor is correct.

```
public StartingViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{

}
```

You are right to do your UI Logic inside `ViewDidLoad()`, the `object reference not set to an object` error is telling you that the label component you are trying to set the text to, does not exist, or rather the reference does not exist.

When you add components to ViewControllers in the storyboard you need to create a reference to the header file.

To do this press and hold Control, and drag a reference to the View Controller's header file.

[image]

When you close xCode Xamarin will sync with your changes and you'll be able to modify the component.

Comment: No offense intended, but this is no good. I and most people I know using Xamarin don't use XCode. They use Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio to make their storyboards. How do we fix this problem in Xamarin or Visual Studio? Literally ALL views created via storybaord are always null when the app hits `ViewDidLoad`, making that method virtually useless unless we stop using storyboards altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the storyboard itself to create the view controller. See the section **Instantiate Storyboards Manually** at [Introduction to Storyboards](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards/).